# How do I draw a rectangle with its height set to fill parent?

Tags: android

I am trying to implement an indicator in an application that shows the volume level of an external device. For this I've created a Layout which is supposed to have Rectangle children being drawn runtime depending on the current volume of said device.

How do I go about accomplishing this? Specifically I wish to draw these rectangles with heights matching that of their parent.

Comment: If what you're asking is  something like the bars in this image http://openclipart.org/detail/116737/music-equalizer-by-merlin2525 , it should be pretty easy to make(without knowing if you want interactivity with those bars).

Answer (score 0):

use a ProgressBar or SeekBar (with touch disabled) views and use their method setProgress(int value) to update.

Comment: Is there a way to override their progress drawables?

Comment: yes. Just put them in a XML layout in eclipse and you'll see the options there.

Answer (score 0):

I think this will help with your quest. It's quite easy actually, just make it a `LinearLayout` with some childs with equal width.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;

public class CustomView extends LinearLayout {
    private ArrayList<ImageView> views = new ArrayList<ImageView>();

    public CustomView(Context context, AttributeSet attributeSet) {
        super(context, attributeSet);
        init(context);
    }

    public CustomView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        init(context);
    }

    private void init(Context context) {
        this.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            ImageView loadingPiece = new ImageView(context);
            loadingPiece.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
            this.addView(loadingPiece);
            LayoutParams layoutParams = (LayoutParams)loadingPiece.getLayoutParams();
            layoutParams.weight = 1.0f;
            layoutParams.height = this.getHeight();
            layoutParams.width = 0;
            loadingPiece.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
            views.add(loadingPiece);
        }
    }

    public void setPercentage(int amountToShow) {
        for (int i = 0; i < views.size(); i++) 
            if (i < amountToShow)
                views.get(i).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            else
                views.get(i).setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    }
}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Pardon my ignorance here. I'd like to try this out but how would you specify where to add this view to the main page?

Comment: @litemode In the XML, add the `CustomView` as `<my.application.example.CustomView ...>` (insert your own package name)